# How to set width in Android/Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am building website using phonegap, problem is i am not able to set width of the page according to screen size of the mobile, i have design my page according to HVGA. what i am not able to do is that the page content to stretch width wise according to the screen size, in any orientation, so that it covers the entire screen.

Comment: how to use and set window.innerWidth

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean setting the viewport ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

Comment: this does not work if the page has content more than the screen width,
is there any way that it squeeze page contents in the screen width??